# No output after button click, since the variable doesn't exist?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, indexoutofboundsexception

I wanted a frame with one TextArea and one Button.
When I press the button, the TextArea should show a food menu of 5 Pizzas, well it shows nothing at all, except for the console which shows

> ```
> "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"  
> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
> at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
> at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
> at de.kvwl.pizza.MainFrame.actionPerformed(MainFrame.java:54)"
> ```

In the method windowsStart() the objects exists and are adjustable.
In the actionPerformed()Method the objects are … kind of invisible, not existing?

```
public void windowStart()
{
    MainFrame mFrame = new MainFrame();
    PizzaReader2 test = new PizzaReader2();
    pPizza = test.csvRead();
    
    System.out.println("\n\n\n" + pPizza.get(0) + "\n\n\n");

    f = new JFrame("Textfield");
    b = new JButton("Menu");
    jt = new JTextArea(10,10);
    JPanel pTextArea = new JPanel();
    b.addActionListener(mFrame);

    pTextArea.add(jt);
    pTextArea.add(b);
    f.add(pTextArea);

    f.setSize(300, 300);
    f.setVisible(true);
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{    
    //jt.setText("TestText");
    System.out.println("\n\n\n" + pPizza.get(0) + "\n\n\n");
     
    String s = e.getActionCommand(); 
    if (s.equals("Menu")) 
    { 
        System.out.println("Button gedrückt");
        //jt.setText("");
        for (int i = 0; i < pPizza.size(); i++) 
        {
            jt.append(pPizza.get(i)+"\n");
        }
```

The TextArea should get the value of the ArrayList

Comment: is it working when you set ```jt.setText("TestText");```?

Comment: Nope, he doesn't find jt either :/

Comment: I dont think that there is a problem with your TextField. IndexOutOfBoundsException looks like your list is empty. Have you tried to print the list to the console? Line 54 could be the line where you call System.out.println("\n\n\n" + pPizza.get(0) + "\n\n\n");

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Comment: Array and List use the same logic in this case. You list is empty, as mentionned in the exception message "_Index: 0, Size: 0_" when you try to get the value at index 0.

Comment: @ItFreak, u are right with the line54 it is System.out.print() but the Method windowStart() has a full list of Pizza I tested it out, all 5 Pizzas are in windowStart().

Comment: Sry forgott to Mention it, my button works fine when I just use a System.out.print("test") and press the button, I got a Output in the console with "test".
When I just try jt.setText("Test") I get a java.lang.NullPointerException.

And it is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your exception occurs in : `at de.kvwl.pizza.MainFrame.actionPerformed(MainFrame.java:54)`

This action is linked during `windowStart` with `b.addActionListener(mFrame);`.

But What I see is that you pass another instance of `MainFrame` called `mFrame` as parameter (as an `ActionListener`). This `mFrame` never load the list with

```
pPizza = test.csvRead();
```

So in short, you have two instance `MainFrame`:

- one created and use to call `windowStart`
- one created in `windowsStart` and use to execute `actionPerformed`.

This last one never load the list of data. Explaining why your list is populated in `windowStart` but not in `actionPerformed`, you are actually using two distinct instance `MainFrame` with two list `pPizza`.

You can correct this by removing this second instance and use `this`, the first instance as an `ActionListener`

```
b.addActionListener(this);
```

Comment: That was the Problem, thanks alot.
And thanks for the Explanation.